# How to change the way coldfusion send the soap response?

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I have a coldfusion webservice which takes in XML data and send back the acknowledgement.

When there is an error the current code returns me the soap response as

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:updatePendingTicketsResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://v02.intouchdataservice">
         <updatePendingTicketsReturn xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><![CDATA[<fault>
<faultcode>TO BE DEFINED IF NEEDED</faultcode>
<faultstring >Content is not allowed in prolog.</faultstring>
<faultactor>InTouch</faultactor>
</fault>]]></updatePendingTicketsReturn>
      </ns1:updatePendingTicketsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But what I would like to have in response is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>TO BE DEFINED IF NEEDED</faultcode>
<faultstring >Content is not allowed in prolog.</faultstring>
<faultactor>InTouch</faultactor>
  </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there a way we can change the way coldfusion sends back the response when there is an exception?

In addition to that, Is there a way we can add an XML schema to the coldfusion WSDL to validate the XML document thats been send ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think no but you can put whole code in try and catch define your own response code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wsdlfile` attribute of `<cfcomponent />` to specify a custom WSDL.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e0e.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78a6.html